# Jest warns of missing prop when it is there

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

How can I suppress this Warning in Jest with this ReactJS component:

> Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `post` was not specified in
>   `MyShowOnePost`.

I'm calling the React component via `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` with the `post` prop.

**MyShowOnePost-test.js**

```
describe('MyShowOnePost', () => {

    const instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <MyShowOnePost post={post} />
    );
```

**MyShowOnePost.js**

```
export default class MyShowOnePost extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        One Post: {this.props.post.content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MyShowOnePost.propTypes = {
  post: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your props won't be available in your testing file-- you need to mock these in some fashion.
This is how I've been writing Jest tests to test Components, which has been working well for my team (note we're using the Enzyme library):

**MyShowOnePost-test.js**

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import MyShowOnePost from './MyShowOnePost'

describe('MyShowOnePost', () => {
  const fakeProps = { post: 'I'm a post!' };

  it('renders the post content', () => {
      const component = mount(<MyShowOnePost post={fakeProps.post} />);

      expect(component.containsMatchingElement(<div>One Post: {'I'm a post!'}</div>).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This has been fairly easy and clean. We do use the enzyme library to mount the component, and if you want to test using snapshots, that would be another way to double check your component is being mounted and rendering correctly.